razor library loading views from different location
My app implements plugin system (razor libraries). App is using razor runtime compilation. Razor library contains few ViewComponents with custom structure described below.
Razor library structure:

Components/SampleComponent.cs
Views/SampleComponent.cshtml

SampleComponent implementation:
public class SampleComponent: ViewComponent
{
    public SampleComponent()
    {
    }

    public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
    {
        // return View($"~/Views/{nameof(SampleComponent)}.cshtml");
        return View($"~/Plugins/MyPlugin1/Views/{nameof(SampleComponent)}.cshtml");
    }
}

Plugins are in this structure in asp.net core app:

Plugins/{plugin_name}
Plugins/{plugin_name}/Views/SampleComponent.cshtml

Problem is if I try to render commented line app is not crashing on render, however it returns empty content. If I render with absolute path then app crashes cause it cant find View cshtml.
I would like to avoid extending IViewLocationExpander.
What can cause my empty content or cant find view problem?
Expected render path:
public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
{
    return View($"~/Plugins/MyPlugin1/Views/{nameof(SampleComponent)}.cshtml");
}

Exception:

InvalidOperationException: The view 'Components/SampleComponent/~/Plugins/MyPlugin1/Views/SampleComponent.cshtml' was not found. The following locations were searched: ~/Plugins/MyPlugin1/Views/SampleComponent.cshtml

EDIT1:
So I figured out I should not copy Views to bin folder but to src folder where asp.net core looks for files during debugging. However empty content render remains.
EDIT2:
Problem with empty rendering solved. Reference to solution: asp.net Core View Component executed but markup not rendered

Problem with path finding failed is due debugging issues. Application is looking for path inside src folder instead binary.
Second problem with empty rendering is caused by rendering component using await Component.InvokeAsync inside parentheses. Fix to proper rendering is explicitly use @await Component.InvokeAsync

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
